# Only variables should be passed by reference bind_param (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

I'm trying to insert records but I'm getting an error in my bind_param? Am I missing something?

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($getbookauthorfname); $i++){
    if($getbookauthorfname[$i] != "" && $getbookauthormname[$i] != "" && $getbookauthorlname[$i] != "" ){
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_author (book_isbn, author_firstname, author_middlename, author_lastname) VALUES (? , ? , ? , ?)";
        $stmt = $mysqlconnection->prepare($query);
        $getbookauthorfname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthorfname[$i]));
        $getbookauthormname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthormname[$i]));
        $getbookauthorlname[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthorlname[$i]));

        $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $getbookisbn, $getbookauthorfname[$i], $getbookauthormname[$i],   $getbookauthorlname[$i]);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: `$getbookauthorfname[$i]` is not a variable.

Comment: It is declared in my isset $getbookauthorfname         = $_POST["author_fname"];
                $getbookauthormname         = $_POST["author_mname"];
                $getbookauthorlname         = $_POST["author_lname"];

Comment: i can show you the whole php code but its too long

Comment: `htmlspecialchars(strip_tags` why? you're using a prepared statement.

Comment: Suggestion: I'd toss using `htmlspecialchars` for input storage, but rather use that whenever you output.

Comment: Think the `prepare()` should be done outside the loop - prepare once and execute many times.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `bind_param` only accepts variables. You're passing an array item, so it won't work.

Try this instead:

```
//...
$fname = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthorfname[$i]));
$mname = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthormname[$i]));
$lname = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($getbookauthorlname[$i]));

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $getbookisbn, $fname, $mname, $lname);
//...
```

Comment: It worked but im trying to insert multiple details in a single submit

Answer (score 0):

I manage to answer my own question i just forgot to put array store to my textboxes thats why im getting the error.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="First Name" id="author_fname[]" name="author_fname[]" required >
```